# Prove that a sequence is monotonically decreasing/increasing

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-writing, monotone-functions

I'm new to real analysis and trying to solve a basic questions. I'm asked to prove that the following sequence is monotonically decreasing:
$b_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^{2k}}{2k+1}$. So I need to prove $b_{n} \leq b_{n+1}$ Now I think I should use induction.

**basisstep:** $b_{1}=\frac{1}{3}$.

**induction hypothesis:** assume $b_{n+1} \geq b_{n}$.

**Proof.** Since $b_{n+1}=b_{n}+\frac{(-1)^{2n+2}}{2n+3}=b_{n}+\frac{1}{2n+3}$. And observe that $\frac{1}{2n+3}>0$. So it follows that $b_{n+1}=b_{n}+\frac{1}{2n+3}>b_{n}$.

Is this a valid proof or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE** First of all, thanks for the fast comments. I now realise I misinterpreted the proof. Instead of proving that the summation is monotonically decreasing, I need to prove that the elements consisting of (1/3,1/5,1/7..1/(2n+1) is monotonically decreasing.

Comment: You need to prove $b_{n+1} \leq b_{n+2}$

Comment: It seems correct to me. But this sequence is monotonically increasing.

Comment: what is your $b_n$?

Comment: i have found it sorry

Comment: I see what you mean with it being monotonically increasing, yet the question states that I need to prove that it decreases... I see that because it is a summation the total sum increases by an ever smaller 'element'.

Answer (score 0):

simplify your calculations and observe that $$(-1)^{2k}=1$$ for all $k$

Comment: good point, thanks